# JS how to block code till promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, authentication, promise, axios

I am trying to make a function called `isAuthenticated()` that returns true or false depending on the authentication state obviously. When the user logs in, I get a token as a response that I store in local storage & use in authentication required requests using the **Bearer** authentication method. Now my code looks like this:

```js
// axios instance

const a = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://mydomain/api",
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
});



const testToken= () => {
   a.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
    "token"
  )}`; // using bearer authintication
  return a.get(`/isLogin`); // api route to check token state
};


// my function

function isAuthenticated() {
  if (!localStorage.token) {
    return false;
  } else {
    testToken()
      .then((response) => {
        return true;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
}


console.log(isAuthenticated()); // this logs undefined
```

My problem is that it logs `undefined`. Now I understand that the reason for this is that the axios `get` method is a promise, & that the code continues execution before it resolves, so my question is: **Is there a way to block code from executing until it resolves?**

I think that there is something fundamentally wrong with my logic, so if you have a proper way of implementing this please help me.

Comment: check out async/await - it'll make your life easier

Comment: @Aadmaa I did, but I don't think I've grasped the concept & I don't know how I might implement it in my code.

Answer (score 1):

When you return value from withing promise callback you return into a void. What you need is change how you call your `isAuthenticated` function:

```js
// axios instance

const a = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://mydomain/api",
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
});



const testToken= () => {
   a.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
    "token"
  )}`; // using bearer authintication
  return a.get(`/isLogin`); // api route to check token state
};


// my function

function isAuthenticated() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    if (!localStorage.token) {
      resolve(false);
    } else {
      testToken()
        .then((response) => {
          resolve(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            resolve(false);
          }
        });
    }
  });
}


isAuthenticated().then((response) =>
{
  if (result)
  {
    //authenticated
  }
  else
  {
    //not authenticated
  }
});
```

You could use `await` to make it less "cumbersome", but still you'll need re-evaluate how you call async functions.

```js
function isAuthenticated(isReject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    setTimeout(() => isReject ? reject("hello word rejected") : resolve("hello world"), 3000); //delay 3sec
  });
}


async function myFunc(id)
{
  const result = await isAuthenticated(id == 3); //wait until promise is resolved
  console.log("result" + id, result);
  return "this was sent to 'then' callback: " + result;
};

console.log("myFunc return", myFunc(1));
console.log("myFunc return2", myFunc(2)
                                .then((result) => console.log("result2 within then:", result)) //this will not fire
                                .catch((result) => console.log("rejected2:", result)));
console.log("myFunc return3", myFunc(3)
                                .then((result) => console.log("result3 within then:", result)) //this will not fire
                                .catch((result) => console.log("rejected3:", result)));
```